# Strip a word to its constituent characters in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have a tensor placeholder of shape `[None, None]` of type `string`. For example, it looks like this

`[["Hello", "World"], ["Amercian", "people"]]`.

Now I want to convert this 2D tensor to a 3D tensor which will basically now strips each word to its constituent characters. So the output looks like
`[[["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"], ["W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]], [["A", "m", "e", "r", "i", "c", "a", "n"], ["p", "e", "o", "p", "l", "e"]]]`.

Since each word has a different number of characters, the new tensor should pad the small words with spaces.
Is there a way to this thing in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This runs

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft

input_data = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.string, name="words")
words_flatten = tf.reshape(words, [tf.shape(words)[0] * tf.shape(words)[1]])
words_split = tf.string_split(words_flatten, delimiter="")
ngrams = tft.ngrams(words_split, ngram_range=(1,3), separator="")
tokens= tf.sparse_reset_shape(tf.sparse_fill_empty_rows(ngrams, "")[0])
tokens_dense = tf.reshape(
            tf.sparse_to_dense(tokens.indices, tokens.dense_shape, tokens.values, default_value=""),
            [tf.shape(words)[0], tf.shape(words)[1], -1]
        )
```

`tokens_dense` is the desired output.